# Nested DTO search

Tags: c#, linq

I have List of DTO Suach as :

```
 Public Class UKey
{
    public Int64 Key{ get; set; }

}

Public Class Test : UKey
{
    public Int64? CityId  { get; set; }
    public Test2  test2{ get; set; }
}
Public Class Test2 : UKey
{
    public Int64? CountryId { get; set; }
    public Test3 test3 {get;set;}
}
public Class Test3 :UKey
{

}
```

I have nested DTOs,for example class test has a member of class test 2 and class test2 has a member of type class test 3,each class has it's own unique key and this key can not be repeated in any of them,somthing like GUid.
I want to query Class Test to find just one of these nested Dtos with the given unique key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `tests` object is `IEnumerable<Test>`, which is a set of `Test` objects;

```
tests.SingleOrDefault(q => q.test2.Key == id || q.test2.test3.Key == id);
```

UPDATE: you need to apply a recursive search. I have changed the base class a bit;

```
public class UKey
{
    public Int64 Key { get; set; }
    public UKey ReferencedEntity { get; set; }
}
```

and the search function:

```
private UKey Search(UKey entity, Int64 id)
    {
        UKey result = null;
        if (entity.Key == id)
            result = entity;
        else
        {
            result = this.Search(entity.ReferencedEntity,id);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer is probably to use a form of [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14497273/120480): If you create a `FindKey` method on your baseclass and implement it accordingly on your derived classes, you can simplify the query:

```
//given: 
//'tests' is a IEnumerable<UKey>
//'g' = a guid you are looking for
tests.SingleOrDefault(q => q.FindKey(g));
```

and the class implementation could look something like this:

```
public abstract class UKey
{              
    public Guid Key{ get; set; }
    public abstract bool FindKey(Guid g);
}

public class Test : UKey
{
    public Int64? CityId  { get; set; }
    public Test2  Test2{ get; set; }

    public override bool FindKey(Guid g){
        return Key == g || (Test2!= null && Test2.FindKey(g));
    }   
}

/*etc.. implement the FindKey method on all you derived classes*/
```